Old horror movie with flying spheres that mechanically chew through people
I saw a movie a long time ago; back when you could switch to a cable channel and never learn the name of the movie you're watching.
Basically the plot goes like: A man's wife is kidnapped. The man and his daughter and son go looking for her in some creepy house. Inside the house I remember the son saying something like, "What's that?" at some kind of metallic indentation in a wall. He responded with something like, "That's a brain sucker". Throughout the film they are chased by these flying spheres that mechanically chew through people; obviously killing them. In the end they all die, and the wife turns out to be some kind of zombie, as just before the kids die the wife easily tugs on her hair and removes a piece of her scalp, then it ends with the kids being snatched through the windows of a hearst they escape in.

Wow, sounds like a feverdream version of the Phantasm series. What is a long time ago to you? American movies? In color? Any more detail helps.

@MeatTrademark long time ago is some time in the 90s. The movie was on American television, and I'm pretty sure it is in color.

Have you sen the Phantasm movies? They prominently feature flying spheres that penetrate your skull.  I don't remember all the details of all five movies.

@MeatTrademark Yes! The movie is Phantasm II
https://youtu.be/DEiQLmCgtdo?t=1h30m45s

@MeatTrademark You can now, if you like.

I hope you know you can answer the question yourself, and get a little more Rep. Just make sure you show why it's the right answer. As BS as it sounds, I have the hiccups right now and have had them almost an hour. PLEASE! Phantasm ball! Bump into my forehead!

No stigma against answering your question, promise.

@MeatTrademark ur funny.

Yes, yes I am...

FYI, that movie was long out of print; the laserdisc version was scarce and fetching high dollar.  A few years ago they finally did release it on DVD.

The movie is named Phantasm II, the second in a series of horror movies. The two younger people I thought were brother and sister are actually girlfriend and boyfriend. The movie isn't on Netflix at the moment. It makes sense I can't remember the movie very well after around twenty years. After watching some clips on YouTube, the movie is pretty gross, too.

You might want to elaborate in which way this fits the details from the question in order to flesh out the answer a little more. And if it is the correct solution to your problem, feel free to accept it.
